# RxJS wait for observable then create another observable, and so on

Tags: angular, rxjs

[image: Tree]

I have a tree like structure in the frontend, that might look like the tree from the image above.
Due to the way, the Backend is designed, I have to persist each node individually. But to persist a node it has to know it's parents id. I decided to persist the nodes in a top down, depth first order, which is `[a,b,d,e,c]`.

I use HttpClient.post() which returns an Observable. To persist `b` I have to wait for `HttpClient.post(a)` to return the id of `a`, which is needed to persist `b`.

The only way I could imagine. Is the following:

```
of(1).pipe(
   mergeMap(() => httpClient.post(a)),
   tap(idOfA => b.parentId = idOfA),
   tap(idOfA => c.parentId = idOfA),
   mergeMap(() => httpClient.post(b)),
   tap(idOfB => d.parentId = idOfB),
   tap(idOfB => e.parentId = idOfB),
   mergeMap(() => httpClient.post(d)),
   mergeMap(() => httpClient.post(e)),
   mergeMap(() => httpClient.post(c))
).subscribe();
```

You could ignore the `tap()` stuff, because it happens automatically in the background. It's just there to make clear, why the request depend on their parents requests to return. Simplified it looks like this:

```
of(1).pipe(
   mergeMap(() => httpClient.post(a)),
   mergeMap(() => httpClient.post(b)),
   mergeMap(() => httpClient.post(d)),
   mergeMap(() => httpClient.post(e)),
   mergeMap(() => httpClient.post(c))
).subscribe();
```

make a request, wait for it to return, make another request and so on. The stuff I implemented above works for any preordered list of 5 nodes. The thing is, I have to do that dynamically, for a list of variable size.

Could you please give me a hint on how to do that in any kind of loop or loop like construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concatMap()` and `parentId` variable stores the latest parent Id -

```
parentId: any;
  
of(a, b, c, d) // or you can also pass an array using from([a, b,c ,d])
.pipe(concatMap(val => httpClient.post('url', { parentId: this.parentId })))
.subscribe(res => {
  this.parentId = res.id;
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and it is much easyer then all my failed attempts. Thank you. :)